# How Do I Integrate An Edit Profile In Nodejs And React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is my react code. i wonder where i got it all wrong

```html
import React, {useState } from "react"; import Inputs, { SelectInput } from "../../components/inputs/Inputs"; import Logo from "../../components/Logo/Logo"; import { StyledEditProfile } from "./StyledEditProfile"; import { Form, Formik } from "formik";
import axios from "axios"; import loadingSvg from "../../assets/img/loading.svg"; import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom" const EditProfile = () => { const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); const location = useLocation() let
data = location.state?.data; const navigate = useNavigate(); const token = localStorage.getItem("user"); const onSubmit = async (values) => { try { setLoading(true) axios .post("http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/update_user", { ...values, }, { headers: {
authorization: `${token}`, } }) .then((response) => { setLoading(false) if (response.status === 200) { navigate("/dashboard/profile"); } }) .catch((err) => { setLoading(true) }); } catch (error) { } }; return (

<StyledEditProfile className="w-full bg-white ">
  <div className="reg_con rounded my-10 p-8">
    <div className="reg_logo flex flex-col items-center rounded">
      <Logo />
    </div>
    <div className="err_msg my-8 text-center text-red-600">

    </div>
    <Formik initialValues={data} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Form action="" className="mt-2">
        <div className="grid gap-4">
          <div className="">
            <Inputs type={ "text"} id={ "FirstName"} label={ "First Name"} name={ "first_name"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="">
            <Inputs type={ "text"} label={ "Last Name"} id={ "LastName"} name={ "last_name"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-2">
          <div className="">
            <Inputs type={ "text"} id={ "UserName"} label={ "Username"} name={ "username"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-2">
          <div className="">
            <Inputs type={ "Email"} id={ "Email"} label={ "Email Address"} name={ "email"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="grid gap-4">
          <div>
            <SelectInput label={ "Country"} name={ "country"} type={ "listbox"} children={[ "Select a country", "Afghanistan", "Iland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Zimbabwe"]} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Inputs label={ "State"} name={ "state"} type={ "text"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <Inputs label={ "City"} name={ "city"} type={ "text"} id={ "City"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-2">
          <div className="">
            <Inputs type={ "text"} id={ "Phone Number"} label={ "Phone Number"} name={ "phone"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4">
          <div className="">
            <Inputs type={ "text"} id={ "Account"} name={ "account"} label={ "Wallet Address"} />
            <div className="fr_erm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="reg_btn flex justify-center mt-8">
          <button type="submit" className="btn" to={ "/Profile"}>
                Update Profile{" "}
                {loading ? (
                  <img
                    srcSet={loadingSvg}
                    alt=""
                    className="inline"
                  />
                ) : null}
              </button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  </div>
</StyledEditProfile>
); }; export default EditProfile;
```

i am a newbiee to react and nodejs and i am trying to create a project where users can update their profile. Everything seeems to be working fine but when i make a change to a user information and click the update button it doesn't go through. Please come to my aid.

This is my react code

> 

```html
import React, {useState } from "react";
import Inputs, { SelectInput } from "../../components/inputs/Inputs";
import Logo from "../../components/Logo/Logo";
import { StyledEditProfile } from "./StyledEditProfile";
import { Form, Formik } from "formik";

import axios from "axios";
import loadingSvg from "../../assets/img/loading.svg";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"



const EditProfile = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation()
  let data = location.state?.data;

  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const token = localStorage.getItem("user");


  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/update_user", {
          ...values,
        }, {
          headers: {
            authorization: `${token}`,
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setLoading(false)

          if (response.status === 200) {
            navigate("/dashboard/profile");
          }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setLoading(true)
        });
    } catch (error) {

    }


  };

  return (

    <StyledEditProfile className="w-full bg-white ">
      <div className="reg_con rounded my-10 p-8">
        <div className="reg_logo flex flex-col items-center rounded">
          <Logo />
        </div>
        <div className="err_msg my-8 text-center text-red-600">

        </div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={data}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
          <Form action="" className="mt-2">
            <div className="grid gap-4">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"FirstName"}
                  label={"First Name"}
                  name={"first_name"}
              
                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  label={"Last Name"}
                  id={"LastName"}
              
                  name={"last_name"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"UserName"}
                  label={"Username"}
                  name={"username"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  
                  type={"Email"}
                  id={"Email"}
                  label={"Email Address"}
                  name={"email"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="grid gap-4">
              <div>
                <SelectInput
                  label={"Country"}
                  name={"country"}
                  type={"listbox"}
                  children={["Select a country", "Afghanistan", "Iland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria",
                    "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola",  "Bulgaria",
   "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"]}
                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Inputs
                  label={"State"}
                  name={"state"}
                  type={"text"}
                 

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <Inputs
                  label={"City"}
                  name={"city"}
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"City"}
                 

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"Phone Number"}
                  label={"Phone Number"}
                  name={"phone"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"Account"}
                  name={"account"}
                  label={"Wallet Address"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="reg_btn flex justify-center mt-8">
              <button type="submit" className="btn" to={"/Profile"} >
                Update Profile{" "}
                {loading ? (
                  <img
                    srcSet={loadingSvg}
                    alt=""
                    className="inline"
                  />
                ) : null}
              </button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </StyledEditProfile>
  );
};

export default EditProfile;
```

```html
import React, {useState } from "react";
import Inputs, { SelectInput } from "../../components/inputs/Inputs";
import Logo from "../../components/Logo/Logo";
import { StyledEditProfile } from "./StyledEditProfile";
import { Form, Formik } from "formik";

import axios from "axios";
import loadingSvg from "../../assets/img/loading.svg";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"



const EditProfile = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation()
  let data = location.state?.data;

  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const token = localStorage.getItem("user");


  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/update_user", {
          ...values,
        }, {
          headers: {
            authorization: `${token}`,
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setLoading(false)

          if (response.status === 200) {
            navigate("/dashboard/profile");
          }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setLoading(true)
        });
    } catch (error) {

    }


  };

  return (

    <StyledEditProfile className="w-full bg-white ">
      <div className="reg_con rounded my-10 p-8">
        <div className="reg_logo flex flex-col items-center rounded">
          <Logo />
        </div>
        <div className="err_msg my-8 text-center text-red-600">

        </div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={data}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
          <Form action="" className="mt-2">
            <div className="grid gap-4">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"FirstName"}
                  label={"First Name"}
                  name={"first_name"}
              
                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  label={"Last Name"}
                  id={"LastName"}
              
                  name={"last_name"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"UserName"}
                  label={"Username"}
                  name={"username"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  
                  type={"Email"}
                  id={"Email"}
                  label={"Email Address"}
                  name={"email"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="grid gap-4">
              <div>
                <SelectInput
                  label={"Country"}
                  name={"country"}
                  type={"listbox"}
                  children={["Select a country", "Afghanistan", "Iland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria",
                    "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua And Barbuda",
                     "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"]}
                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Inputs
                  label={"State"}
                  name={"state"}
                  type={"text"}
                 

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <Inputs
                  label={"City"}
                  name={"city"}
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"City"}
                 

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"Phone Number"}
                  label={"Phone Number"}
                  name={"phone"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
              <div className="">
                <Inputs
                  type={"text"}
                  id={"Account"}
                  name={"account"}
                  label={"Wallet Address"}

                />
                <div className="fr_erm">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="reg_btn flex justify-center mt-8">
              <button type="submit" className="btn" to={"/Profile"} >
                Update Profile{" "}
                {loading ? (
                  <img
                    srcSet={loadingSvg}
                    alt=""
                    className="inline"
                  />
                ) : null}
              </button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </StyledEditProfile>
  );
};

export default EditProfile;
```

Comment: Any output in the console? Any errors? Check the network tab in dev tools to see what your request looks like when being sent to make sure it is what you're expecting)

Comment: xhr.js:220          POST http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/update_user net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.... This is the error i am getting sir

Comment: {id: 16, first_name: "Favour", last_name: "Ehiwario", email: "fay@gmail.com", country: "Poland",…}
account: "1223224434343"
city: "Lagos"
country: "Poland"
createdAt: "2022-09-03"
email: "fay@gmail.com"
first_name: "Favour"
id: 16
last_name: "Ehiwario"
password: "$2b$10$ftvv6.ShRC98qu2wpI1w1OnXO4PcllmZbEN68xhBrtmYrLFceVKFS"
phone: "08100158542"
state: "lagos"
updatedAt: "18:22:11"
username: "wweee"..... In the network portion. it is displaying the data

Comment: Connection refused suggest that whatever you think is hosted on localhost:5000, is not actually hosted there, make sure that your server you have setup is running.

Comment: what do you think sir

Comment: const updateUserController = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    userId = req.payload.dataValues.id;
    if (!userId) throw createHttpError.Unauthorized("Invalid User Id");
    const user = await User.update(req.body, {
      where: {
        id: req.body.id
      }
    });
    if (!user) throw createHttpError.NotFound("User Not Found");
    res.send({
      status: 200,
      user: user
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
This is my nodejs handling the update user, everything seems fine

Comment: IT HAS WORKED!!!!!!GOD BLESS YOU, YOU JUST MADE MY DAY.THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the answer to this was that the server was that the server recieving the call was not running.